# Adding existing function to subclass

Tags: python, subclass

I am making a few sub-classes that needs to implement a `run` method. They all follow a pattern:

```
from mylib import transformation_function_1
from mylib import transformation_function_2

def SubClass1(ParentClass):
    def run(self):
        subclass_data = transformation_function_1(self.parent_data)
        # Some other fixed logic.

def SubClass2(ParentClass):
    def run(self):
        subclass_data = transformation_function_2(self.parent_data)
        # Some other fixed logic.
```

Is there anyway I can pull out this logic in a intermediate class? Something like this?

```
from mylib import transformation_function_1
from mylib import transformation_function_2

def TransformationBase(ParentClass):

    @abstractclassmethod
    def transformation_function():
        raise NotImplementedError

    def run(self):
        subclass_data = transformation_function(self.parent_data)
        # Some other fixed logic.

def SubClass1(TransformationBase):
    transformation_function = transformation_function_1

def SubClass2(TransformationBase):
    transformation_function = transformation_function_2
```

Thanks!

Comment: So your issue is that the functions that each subclass should implement are already defined elsewhere and you want to reuse them? I'd say you implement the functions in the subclasses as you should, and just call the according external function from it.

Comment: Hard to understand why you speak of classes while your code defines functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special function `staticmethod` allows to declare local methods as being static. Assuming that you wanted to declare classes and that you want that subclasses make use of *external* free functions, you could do:

```
>>> class TransformationBase:

    def transformation_function():
        raise NotImplementedError

    def run(self):
        subclass_data = self.transformation_function(self.parent_data)
        # Some other fixed logic.


>>> def transformation_function_1(data):
    print('F1', data)


>>> def transformation_function_2(data):
    print('F2', data)
    return 2

>>> class SubClass1(TransformationBase):
    transformation_function = staticmethod(transformation_function_1)
    parent_data = "P1"


>>> c1 = SubClass1()
>>> c1.run()
F1 P1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
class SubClass(TransformationBase):
  def transformation_function(*args, **kwargs):
    return transformation_function1(*args, **kwargs)
```